# MVC getting back calulated data from Model to Controller

Tags: java, model-view-controller

Controller ask Model to calculate data, to do it Model run recursive method, while this method is on i would like to update View and inform user about it progress.
I could simply do it by passing to Model an object of Constructor class and use it to update view by method while recursive method is on, but according to MVC pattern Constructor -> Model communication is just one way.
What's the best way to solve it, which would not infringe MVC pattern.

Comment: The model could raise an event to which the controller listens.  Every time the event is raised, the controller can get data from that event and update the view.  (This is assuming that all of this is running in separate contexts and not purely single-threaded.)

Comment: This, essentially. I use AjaxForms everywhere in MVC, and they allow you to provide 'live feeds' of data from the controller very easily. I prefer to have my crud pages separated into strict sets of partial views that I can wrap inside AjaxForms in order to show loading bars, new notes, other updates to the data etc.

Comment: Thank you David i did it by implementing event listener interface.